# Change target URL after getting results in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, url

I've been looking into stackoverflow over this but it has not been clear to me. I have an Ajax function in Jquery that suits me very well.
This connects to a php script remotely and returns me some results, after returning those results, I use the same form to treat the results and publish them, but the second step is no longer done through AJAX but through pure PHP. I would like that second step also done with AJAX so that I thought that after getting the results, the AJAX URL would change to the address where my second PHP script (locally stored) is located.

```
$('[id^="form-busqueda"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'https://example.com/script1.php',
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'./assets/img/loading.svg" />');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data); // GET DATA
            $('[id^="form-busqueda"]').prop('action','?page='+plugin_page_id+'&publicar=si'); // Change the target attr (for second step)
            $('[id^="form-busqueda"]').unbind('submit'); //unbind event
        });
    });
```

As you can see in my code, once I get the results, I set a target for the attribute "action" of the form and that way I use the same form to publish the results obtained previously.

What I would like now would be to use that same form but once I get the results, I change the ajax URL to handle my second PHP script. Something like this:

```
    $('[id^="form-busqueda"]').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'https://example.com/script1.php',
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#result').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'./assets/img/loading.svg" />');
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data); // GET DATA
              $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : pluginUrl+'./script2.php',
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#result').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'./assets/img/loading.svg" />');
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data); // GET DATA
            });
                $('[id^="form-busqueda"]').unbind('submit'); //unbind event
            });
        });
```

I know that syntax is wrong but it is more or less what I had thought of, I was also thinking about the possibility of changing the ID of the form and then treating it in a new AJAX function but I do not know if there would be another more elegant option.

Comment: "I know that syntax is wrong" What specifically do you think is wrong? Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I did the test and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to what I think you are, then something like this might work (it worked for me but a time ago and I don't remember exactly the code that I've used)

```
$('[id^="form-busqueda"]').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'https://example.com/script1.php',
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="'+pluginUrl+'./assets/img/loading.svg" />');
            }
            success: //Your code here
        })
});
```

If this doesn't work or I got wrong what you've tried to said, ask me again :)

Comment: What I want is to change the URL in AJAX once I have already obtained the results.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way to do it (I only needed to do this one time) but I inserted an AJAX inside an AJAX, after success (where I put the "//Your code here" comment, is where the new AJAX would be), if that doesn't work for you I'll try to come up with a new idea